# Django rest framework use serializer_class in viewset @detail_route

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm using **viewsets** with a lot of `@detail_route` and `@list_route`. In normal viewsets i use `serializer_class` and then some validation in serializer but in `@detail_route`

I'm creating serializer in view and check validation here - I know its bad.

My question is how to use `@detail_route` to use like normal `modelviewset` without need creating serializer manually but use `serializer_class` in decorator.

Its possible to do pagnitation without any addional code in `@detail_route`?

Its better to refactor code and move `@detail_route` and `@list_route` to seperated viewsets or stay on viewsets methods?

```
@rest_framework.decorators.detail_route(methods=['post'],
                                        serializer_class=orders_serializers.ChangeOrderStatusSerializer)
def change_status(self, request, pk=None):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        new_status = serializer.validated_data.get('status')
        order = self.get_object()

            if new_status in [orders_models.Order.EXECUTE, orders_models.Order.OUTSIDE]:
                order.status = new_status
                order.save()

                return Response({
                    'status': order.get_status_display()
                }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response('This new status is invalid for this order.',
                                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: For the detail route that you provided it looks a lot like you just need to PATCH order model providing only status field as payload, you don't need different route for that.

Comment: @GabrielMuj yes i know but i want do this this way because I have others functionality in detail_route and there cant use PATH.